# Could I embed tag manager into chrome extension?

Tags: google-tag-manager

Is there any way to inject google Tag Manager into the my Chrome extension.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try this guide and replace the code with the tag manager: https://davidsimpson.me/2014/05/27/add-googles-universal-analytics-tracking-chrome-extension/

Comment: Hi Mindbreaker. I know how implement GA. My question is about Tag Manager.

Comment: @StanislauLadutska Hi! Did you ever figure this out? I am trying to do the same thing and can't find any information on this anywhere

Comment: Hi @MRB, unfortunately no.